# Find best-fit parabola to the given data

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, least-squares

> Find the parabola $At^2+Bt+C$ that best approximates the data set $t= -1,0,1,2,3$ and $b(t) = 5,2,1,2,5$.

Would I be using least squares such that $x = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Closet parabola" will look cleaner as "Closest parabola".

Comment: Yes, you would do that in the general case.  Here the symmetry of the numbers shows your parabola is $(t-1)^2+1$ and it fits perfectly.

Comment: @Ross Millikan Your comment deserves to be transformed into a perfect  answer.

Answer (score 3):

The normal equations will solve the general case.  In your specific case, the values of $b(t)$ are symmetric around $t=1$, so the parabola must be $A(t-1)^2+(C-1)$.  Using the point at $t=1$ we can see that $C=2$, then a quick check shows $A=1$ and we have $b(t)=(t-1)^2+1$, which fits the points perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating on what @callculus said we can do

[image]

Which in your case looks like this

[image]

then just solve for A, B, and C.

You can check you answer by looking at your final equation.

Comment: Shouldn't the sum(ti) in your right-hand vector be sum(b(ti))?  sum(ti) doesn't actually sum to 15.  sum(b(ti)) does, as does sum(ti^2)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: In your case

$A=\begin{pmatrix}{} n&\sum_{i=1}^5 t_i & \sum_{i=1}^5 t_i^2 \\ \sum_{i=1}^5 t_i & \sum_{i=1}^5 t_i^2 & \sum_{i=1}^5 t_i^3 \\ \sum_{i=1}^5 t_i^2 & \sum_{i=1}^5 t_i^3 & \sum_{i=1}^5 t_i^4\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}{} 5 & 5 & 15 \\ 5 & 15 & 35 \\ 15 & 35 & 99 \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

**Problem statement**

Given a sequence of $m=5$ data points $\left\{ x_{k}, y_{k} \right\}_{k=1}^{m}$, and the trial function
$$
 y(x) = a_{0} + a_{1} x + a_{2} x^{2}.
$$
The linear system is
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} a &= y\\
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 1 & -1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 & 4 \\
 1 & 3 & 9 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 a_{0} \\
 a_{1} \\
 a_{2} 
\end{array}
\right]
%
& =
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 5 \\
 2 \\
 1 \\
 2 \\
 5 
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$

**Solution via normal equations**

The normal equations are
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} a  & = \mathbf{A}^{*} y \\
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 5 & 5 & 15 \\
 5 & 15 & 35 \\
 15 & 35 & 99 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 a_{0} \\
 a_{1} \\
 a_{2} 
\end{array}
\right]
%
&=
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 15 \\
 15 \\
 59 
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$
The solution is 
$$
 \begin{align}
   a_{LS}  & = \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} \right)^{-1}
  \mathbf{A}^{*} y \\
%
&=
\frac{1}{70}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 26 & 3 & -5 \\
 3 & 27 & -10 \\
 -5 & -10 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 15 \\
 15 \\
 59 
\end{array}
\right] \\
%
&=
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
  2 \\
 -2 \\
  1 
\end{array}
\right],
%
\end{align}
$$
$$
  y(x) = 2 -2x + x^{2}.
$$
This is an exact fit because 
$$
r^{2} = 
\left( \mathbf{A} a_{LS} - b \right)^{*}
\left( \mathbf{A} a_{LS} - b \right) = 0.
$$

The plot shows the solution against the data points.

[image: Data and solution]